# Is there a way to use sqldf Group By to return results by rolling periods in R?

Tags: r, group-by, sqldf

I have a set of data in which respondents can answer multiple times in each month.

```
structure(list(Month = c("Jan 2016", "Jan 2016", "Feb 2016", 
"Feb 2016", "Mar 2016", "Apr 2016", "May 2016", "Jun 2016", "Jun 2016", 
"Jul 2016", "Aug 2016", "Aug 2016", "Sep 2016", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", 
"Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2016", "Feb 2016", "Feb 2016", 
"Feb 2016", "Mar 2016", "Mar 2016", "Apr 2016", "May 2016", "May 2016", 
"Jun 2016", "Jun 2016", "Jul 2016", "Aug 2016", "Aug 2016", "Oct 2016", 
"Oct 2016", "Dec 2016", "Mar 2016", "Mar 2016", "Apr 2016", "Apr 2016", 
"May 2016", "Jun 2016", "Aug 2016", "Sep 2016", "Jan 2016", "Jan 2016", 
"Feb 2016", "Feb 2016", "Feb 2016", "Feb 2016", "Feb 2016"), 
    PhysicianID = c(4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 
    4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 4263, 
    4263, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 
    4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4278, 4282, 4282, 
    4282, 4282, 4282, 4282, 4282, 4282, 4309, 4309, 4309, 4309, 
    4309, 4309, 4309)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I need to know the unique count of respondents for rolling 3 month periods. Getting the results by each month is not a problem:

```
sqldf("SELECT Month,COUNT(distinct(PhysicianID)) FROM Data_for_R GROUP BY Month")
```

```
      Month COUNT(distinct(PhysicianID))
1  Apr 2016                            3
2  Aug 2016                            3
3  Dec 2016                            2
4  Feb 2016                            3
5  Jan 2016                            3
6  Jul 2016                            2
7  Jun 2016                            3
8  Mar 2016                            3
9  May 2016                            3
10 Nov 2016                            1
11 Oct 2016                            2
12 Sep 2016                            2
```

What I need is a way to return results that look more like

```
1 Jan 2016 to March 2016              xxx
2 Feb 2016 to April 2016              xxx
3 March 2016 to May 2016              xxx
etc...
```

Comment: Question updated - apologies!

Comment: sorry, first post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the year/month to yearmon class (which when sent to SQL will appear as year + 0 for Jan, 1/12 for Feb, etc.) and then left join the months with the data matching the 3 trailing months taking floating point approximation into account. Group on the current month and perform the count. Only keep rows for which there are three months -- you may or may not want that.  The name__class method assigns the indicated class to variable names having a suffix of __ and a class name.

```
library(sqldf)
library(zoo)

DFR <- transform(Data_for_R, Month = as.yearmon(Month, "%b %Y"))
Mos <- data.frame(Month = seq(min(DFR$Month), max(DFR$Month), 1/12))

sqldf("select 
    min(b.Month) From__yearmon, 
    max(b.Month) To__yearmon, 
    count(distinct b.PhysicianID) Num
  from 
    Mos a 
    left join DFR b 
      on b.Month between a.Month - 2./12.- 0.001 and a.Month + 0.001
  group by a.Month
  having count(distinct b.Month) = 3
", method = "name__class")
```

giving

```
       From       To Num
1  Jan 2016 Mar 2016   4
2  Feb 2016 Apr 2016   4
3  Mar 2016 May 2016   3
4  Apr 2016 Jun 2016   3
5  May 2016 Jul 2016   3
6  Jun 2016 Aug 2016   3
7  Jul 2016 Sep 2016   3
8  Aug 2016 Oct 2016   3
9  Sep 2016 Nov 2016   3
10 Oct 2016 Dec 2016   2
```

### Update

Updated to handle the situation where there are missing months.  On the sample data in the question it gives the same answer as before since there were no missing months.